# How do I grant privilege for a user to SSH into a Solaris machine?

Tags: ssh, solaris, solaris-10

I'm not sure how to do this. Documentation is not clear at all. I can get root privilege/be root so that's not a problem, I just don't know what to do.

I'm thinking it's either modifying the sshd_config file (AllowUsers?) or else there is some line command that grants the privilege.

Also, it would be nice if I could "dry run" the config file, as I need to restart the ssh daemon and my only access to the machine is via ssh, so it would be great if I didn't bunk that up.

A clear answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Restarting the ssh service doesn't break the existing ssh connections so you should be able to test your settings without (too much) risk.

Comment: OK, that's good to know.

Answer (score 2):

If that user already exists, and SSH is in it's default configuration, you don't need to do anything. Unless you (or a predecessor) have restricted which users are allowed, sshd will allow any existing user to SSH in to the box. If there is an error message you are getting, you'll need to add it to the original post so we can see what's happening.

Comment: There are no error messages.  It just seems to reject the password.  It doesn't reject the password for root.

Comment: What appears in the logs? If it thinks you're getting the password wrong, it'll show an "authentication failed" message in your system logs.

Comment: Ugh.  It turned out to be a password problem.  Thank you!

Comment: It won't let me select the answer.  I am trying to merge with my StackOverflow identity.  Guess I don't know how the different exchanges play together....